# Using Frama-C to slice from a large project

Tags: frama-c, program-slicing

I am trying to experiment with Frama-C against a large code base.

I am using GnuTLS as a target project and directing Frama-C to slice from a source file in this project according to a specific statement.

I used the following command

```
frama-c -eva -slicing-verbose 8 -no-cpp-frama-c-compliant -cpp-command `gcc ...` -kernel-warn-key annot-error=active -slice-calls some_call_in_a_function file.c
```

When I run this command I get the following error:

```
[kernel:annot-error] FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/sys/uio.h:57: Warning:
  unbound logic variable __FC_MAX_OPEN_FILES. Ignoring specification of function writev
[kernel] FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/sys/socket.h:290: User Error:
  Cannot resolve variable __FC_MAX_OPEN_SOCKETS
  288   struct __fc_sockfds_type { int x; };
  289   #endif
  290   //@ ghost struct __fc_sockfds_type __fc_sockfds[__FC_MAX_OPEN_SOCKETS];
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  291
  292   /* Represents the creation of new file descriptors for sockets. */
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

Does anyone know what's going on here ?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question. Notably, the exact argument of `-cpp-command` you pass to Frama-C is very important. Moreover, if you could provide a minimal `file.c` that reproduces the issue, it would also help.

Comment: As Virgile mentioned, the issue must be related to your usage of `-cpp-command`. Note that it is very uncommon to need `-no-cpp-frama-c-compliant`, especially when using GCC. I assume you had some parsing error and tried using `-cpp-command` to fix it (instead of just `-cpp-extra-args`, which is enough in most cases), which led to another error.

Comment: This is my -cpp-command `gcc -E -C -I. -I/tmp/__fc_machdepe93e76.dir -I/root/.opam/4.14.1/share/frama-c/share/libc -D__FRAMAC__ -dD -nostdinc -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -Wno-unknown-warning-option -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -I./../gl -I./../gl -I./includes -I./x509 -I./includes -I./includes -I./x509 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1 -DPIC`

Comment: Without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to tell for sure, but there's a good chance that the issue lies in the presence of `-I/usr/include`, and `-I/usr/local/include`: Mixing your system's headers with Frama-C's own headers is known not to work well. You may want to have a look at this [blog post](https://www.frama-c.com/2018/07/06/Parsing-realistic-code-bases-with-Frama-C.html) which contains valuable information on how to set up an analysis for bigger code base